# PWM only works after touched with oscillicope probe

Tags: pwm, oscilloscope, netduino, probe

I am using two PWM outputs from a Netduino 2 to control two servos. One of the PWM pins works perfectly fine but the other doesn't work until I have touched it with an oscope probe. The probe doesn't need to remain connected or even grounded. Just a small tap gets it running.

I removed the pin headers so I could directly solder the wires to the PCB so perhaps I damaged something? It's strange because everything works fine after I tap the connection with the probe. Both servos are powered and grounded from the same rails.

Any ideas/solutions?

Comment: Could it be a cold joint?

Comment: If you touch it with something non-conducting does it have the same effect?

Comment: Could it be configured as an open-drain output and you need a pullup to make it work reliably?

Comment: I just switched to another PWM port. I don't think it was a cold joint, the joint looked pretty solid and I re soldered it twice to make sure.

Comment: Can you show a circuit diagram and photo of what you built?

Comment: A start-up issue?  You could try adding a bit of resistance to ground.  Did you forget an output cap?